# How to restrict the growth of local collection of entities in EF 4.1.?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity

---

Hi, I have written a parser which parse code files and save language constructs(Properties,Methods,events,functions,subroutines) to db using  EF 4.1.
There is only a single instance of DBContext which is used throughout the parsing.

Each file during parsing creates various objects of entities and save the dbcontext once that file is parsed.
But, now even after save, if we check the local collection of any entity, it still shows the objects in memory like : DbContext.EntityName.Local

So, after parsing couple of files, the inmemory local collection of entities keep growing ad consumes a considerable amount of memory, resulting into hanging-up the entire process.

Is there a way to clear the local collection of entities without calling dispose().?

Comment: Use a new context for each parsed file.

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes I parse around 1500 files in one execution , so I cant create 1500 instances of DBContext.!! :(

Comment: Of course you can. There is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Contexts should be short lived for this very reason.

You could always `Detach` your entities after you have saved it.

Comment: Thanks podiluska, but as I am using DbContext and not ObjectContext, I don't get any option of detaching an entity.Also, if I do that by casting DbContext to ObjectContext,I cant detach them after parsing of each file as I parse multiple files at one go.